# Proving that, for positive integers $k_i$, there exists $x_0\in[0,\pi]$, such that $\frac12+\sum_{i = 1}^m\cos(k_ix_0)<0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, trigonometry

> $k_i$ is a positive integer, $i=1,\ldots,m$, please try to prove that there exist a point $x_0 \in [0,\pi]$, such that $\frac{1}{2}+\sum\limits_{i = 1}^m {\cos ({k_i}{x_0})} < 0$.

**My attempt:**

If $k_i$ are all equal, this question is easy;

If $k_i$ forms an arithmetic sequence, using the product to difference formulas, we can simplify the expression $\frac{1}{2}+\sum\limits_{i = 1}^m {\cos ({k_i}{x})}$, for example, $\frac{1}{2} + \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\cos (ix)}  = \frac{{\sin \frac{{(2n + 1)}}{2}x}}{{2\sin \frac{x}{2}}}$.

Now, however, $k_i$ are disorganized.

Comment: You might have more success writing $\cos(k_i x_0)$ as $\Re\left( \exp(\mathrm{i}k_i x_0) \right)$, so your sum becomes a polynomial in the variable $\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}x_0}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $k_1, \ldots, k_m \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$ be (not necessarily distinct) positive integers. Define $f(\theta)$ by

$$ f(\theta) = \sum_{i=1}^{m} \cos(k_i \theta). $$

Then by noting that $\int_{0}^{\pi} \cos(k\theta) \, \mathrm{d}\theta = \pi \mathbf{1}_{\{k=0\}} $ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, we get

$$ \int_{0}^{\pi} f(\theta) \, \mathrm{d}\theta = 0. \tag{1}\label{e:1} $$

Moreover,

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\pi} f(\theta)^2 \, \mathrm{d}\theta
&= \sum_{i = 1}^{m}\sum_{j=1}^{m} \int_{0}^{\pi} \cos(k_i\theta)\cos(k_j\theta) \, \mathrm{d}\theta \\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^{m}\sum_{j=1}^{m} \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\cos((k_i + k_j)\theta) + \cos((k_i - k_j)\theta)}{2} \, \mathrm{d}\theta \\
&= \sum_{i = 1}^{m} \underbrace{ \sum_{j=1}^{m} \frac{\pi}{2} \mathbf{1}_{\{ k_i = k_j \}} }_{\geq \frac{\pi}{2}}
\geq \frac{m \pi}{2}. \tag{2}\label{e:2}
\end{align*}

So by combining $\eqref{e:1}$ and $\eqref{e:2}$, we get

\begin{align*}
\frac{m\pi}{2} + \frac{\pi}{4}
\leq \int_{0}^{\pi} \left( f(\theta)^2 + \frac{1}{4} \right) \, \mathrm{d}\theta
= \int_{0}^{\pi} \left( f(\theta) + \frac{1}{2} \right)^2 \, \mathrm{d}\theta. \tag{3}\label{e:3}
\end{align*}

Now assume that $f(\theta) + \frac{1}{2} \geq 0$ for all $\theta \in [0, \pi]$ for the sake of contradiction. Since $f(\theta) \leq m$ for all $\theta$, the RHS of $\eqref{e:3}$ is bounded as follows:

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\pi} \left( f(\theta) + \frac{1}{2} \right)^2 \, \mathrm{d}\theta
&\leq \int_{0}^{\pi} \left(m + \frac{1}{2} \right) \left( f(\theta) + \frac{1}{2} \right) \, \mathrm{d}\theta \tag{4}\label{e:4} \\
&= \left(m + \frac{1}{2} \right) \frac{\pi}{2} \\
&= \frac{m \pi}{2} + \frac{\pi}{4} \tag{5}\label{e:5}
\end{align*}

Since the inequalities $\eqref{e:3}-\eqref{e:5}$ are saturated (meaning that all the intermediate quantities are bounded from above/below by the same number), all the inequalities therein are actually equalities.

In particular, subtracting LHS of $\eqref{e:4}$ from RHS gives

$$ \int_{0}^{\pi} \underbrace{ (m - f(\theta)) \left( f(\theta) + \frac{1}{2} \right) }_{\geq 0 \text{ by the assumption}} \, \mathrm{d}\theta = 0. $$

Since the integrand is continuous, this implies that

$$ f(\theta) = -\frac{1}{2} \qquad\text{or}\qquad f(\theta) = m $$

for all $\theta \in [0, \pi]$. Since $f$ is continuous and $f(0) = m$, we conclude that $f$ is constant with value $m$ on $[0, \pi]$, which is clearly a contradiction. (For example, note that $f''(0) = -\sum_{i=1}^{m} k_i^2 < 0$.) $\square$

Comment: Nice answer! Actually, you can get $f(\theta)\equiv m,\forall \theta\in[0,\pi]$, because $f(0)=m$.

Comment: @Riemann, Thank you for the comment :) Indeed it would be a more natural way of thinking to argue that the condition forces $f$ to be constant with the value $f(0)=m$.

Comment: To the downvoter: Would you kindly let me know what is not good about my answer so I can improve it?

Comment: What a wonderful answer!

Comment: @zeyuhao, Glad it helped :)

Comment: By continuity, we can get  $x_0\in(0,\pi)$.